# Placing code behind code in the aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i have a variable which i am setting in the code behind which is

protected int intPermission;

In my aspx page I have this piece of code

```
  <% if (Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
       { %>
        <span class="feed_link">
            <a class="comment reply"></a>
        </span>
    <%} %>
```

I am trying to add the intPermission variable in the if statement however i am getting syntax errors.

I want it to be like this

```
if (Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && intPermission == 1 || Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && intPermission == 2)
```

How do i go about doing this?

Comment: Please don't show us artificial examples, show us your real source code and the real error message.

Comment: No that is the real source code, in order to save space i did not want to put the whole page there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`PlaceHolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx). Then use its `Visible` property to set it from the code behind.

Comment: I agree. This would be much better approach. But it doesn't answer the question where is syntax error in the current pmillio's spaghetti code.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to public

```
public int intPermission;
```

And perhaps use brackets in the if-statement

```
if ((Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && intPermission == 1) || (Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && intPermission == 2))
```

Comment: `public` is a bad idea here. use `protected`.

Comment: The whole approach the OP took, is a bad idea. I suggested public because it is least limiting, and the OP can rule out inaccessibilty because of protection level.